# How can I get audio when I speed up playback of a DVD in Windows Media Player?

Tags: video, audio, dvd, speed, windows-media-player

In Windows Media Player there's an option
Enhancements->Play Speed Settings
which lets you change the playback speed.

When playing audio files (mp3 etc) it works fine and does pitch correction etc.

Likewise avi files - they play fine too at increased speeds.

However, when playing a DVD at increased speed, the audio is silenced. Video plays fast but there's no sound.

Can anyone figure out how to get it to work?

BTW This is on Windows 7, WMP 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since discovered that the most recent versions of VLC can do variable speed playback with appropriate audio pitch correction. And this includes when playing a physical DVD. VLC FTW!

Comment: VLC is always win. :)